# Determine which libraries are references by a native DLL

Tags: dll, reference, native

I am a .NET developer, and in the .NET world finding out which assemblies are referenced by an assembly is easy:

I can inspect the assembly using many available tools to see the assemblies it references.

This does not cover cases where assemblies are loaded dynamically somehow, but still gives some estimate.

Is there a similar process for native DLLs? Can i take a dll and find out which DLLs it uses ?

I am using a native COM library, however i am not sure which components (DLLs) should be redistributed with my own application. This information is not found in the documentation of this library as well (QC OTA API).